# History Slider with moving pagination (year) in SwiperJS

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to develope a history slider with SwiperJS. The pagination sits vertically on the left side and consists of the year, which is set into a data-attribute of each slide. The slides are aligned horizontally.

The active pagination entry should move to the center of the pagination. Is this natively possible within SwiperJS or does this need some modification and additional Javascript?

I attached an image that shows what I have in mind.
I'm using the latest SwiperJS version v10.0.4.

[image]

Thanks,
Alex